# How to create an array of images and store it in mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I want to make a post feed nodejs app, where in user will upload max 10 images with a short description about it just like instagram and facebook. I'm able to store the images using express-fileupload npm package but how to create an array of that images and store it into mongodb.

I have made a PostSchema that looks like this

```
var postSchema = new schema({
    username: {
        type: String
    },
    photos: {
        type: Array
    },
    videos: {
        type: Array
    },
    likes: {
        type: Array,
    },
    description: {
        type: String
    }
})
```

and the postfeed controller looks like this

```
router.post('/post', verifyToken, (req, res) => {
    var description = req.body.description
    var email = req.body.email

    if (req.files) {
        var file = req.files.photos;
        for (let i = 0; i < file.length; i++) {

            var path = appRoot + '/uploads/posts/' + req.user._id
            fs.mkdir(path, () => {})
            var postImages = path + '/' + file[i].md5 + '-' + Date.now() + '.png'
            file[i].mv(postImages)
        }
    }
})
```

Comment: Just store the result of fs read

Answer (score 0):

There are couple of ways you can do depends on file size, try using data type as '**binData**'to store images to mongoDB. If file size exceeds 16mb then you need to start looking into **GridFS** : [enter link description here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/gridfs/) as you're looking to store an array of images then check these useful links:
[enter link description here](https://medium.com/@alvenw/how-to-store-images-to-mongodb-with-node-js-fb3905c37e6d) and [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56093124/how-to-save-an-array-of-files-to-mongodb-database-using-multer)

As a suggestion if your project has cloud infrastructure it would be very easy to store image files in AWS S3 or Azure blob and have the respective links stored as an array in mongoDB collection(What we're doing and better suitable implementation these days), with that UI can render those images from provided links directly accessing from cloud.